# Ability to activate the Okta activation token programatically

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

Does Okta have the ability to check the activation token programmatically without the user browsing to the site.

The activation token comes as part of the url from calling this api: {{url}}/api/v1/users/00u4invit2tTNJ1Gf0h7/lifecycle/activate?sendEmail=false
Per request: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#activate-user

If there is not, what is the recommended method for sending a custom activation email to the user without the user going through Okta's activation wizard.  We would like for the user go to through our own activation wizard after clicking on the activation email.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom activation logic you would want to implement your own portal site. You will still email the Okta token to the user but do user activation in your portal site through the API. We have done this in the past without any trouble.